# Creating an outgoing call using Asterisk Manager and "pyst"

Tags: python, asterisk

I am trying to write some automation tests which make a phone call to my local Asterisk instance and then check that a receiving SIP client has received the call.

It is my understanding that I can create an outgoing call event using the Asterisk Manager. To do this I have been trying to use the Python 'pyst' library.

I have not been able to find any working examples of how to implement this scenario. From the information I have managed to gather, I have come up with this script:

```
from asterisk import manager

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 5068

m = manager.Manager()

m.connect( HOST )

m.login( 'admin', 'temp123' )
targetURL = '441610000001'

response = m.originate(
    targetURL ,
    's',
    context='outgoing',
    priority='1'
    )

print m.status()

m.logoff()

m.close()
```

This script reports a 'success' response from Asterisk Manager but does not actually create an outgoing call.

Has anyone written a script to do this in python?

I am only familiar with the Python language so solutions in other languages wouldn't be very helpful for me!

Answer (score 1):

Please read again documentation

"Targeturl" in your program actually have be channel, so in your code it have no channel type and host(if that sip).

Valid examples are:

```
 targetURL = 'SIP/441610000001@myprovider_name'
 targetURL = 'Local/441610000001@outbound_context'
```

Context "outbound" have be valid and have deliver call.

PYST is opensource framework. If you are realy "familar" with python, i recommend you read source of originate method and check what it send with asterisk doc

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+Originate

Note: it is very bad idea program for asterisk using framework like PYST if you have no general knowledge about asterisk itself. First you need read asterisk book.